# Some pistons won't extend in complex creations

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The piston extender fully extends with a circuit. The same piston extender/circuit jams in large or complex creations even though there's no redstone interference. Do i need a more powerful computer?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the circuits?

Comment: redstone doesnt interfere. the machine uses tnt that is supposed to be compacted but fails

Comment: We still need a screenshot to understand the problem.

Comment: The answer to the question you actually asked is: No, in almost all cases Minecraft still does everything in the same order. I think even if it skips ticks because it's lagging 60s behind, it still does everything in the same order, just later. The only thing that is affected by lag is the world border for some reason. But that's not the answer you need, you need actual redstone advice.

Comment: It's likely that in these complex creations there's something in the way of these pistons rather than the pistons lagging. I find it most likely that the pistons are instead activating at the wrong time in the full circuit as you have forgotten to account for tick delay from certain repeaters/redstone torches.

Comment: the directional bias in minecraft is a waste of time